# Not able to access files inside folder in SwiftUI project, getting NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to access some files in a folder, but I am having trouble doing so. As of now, this is the code I have:

```
import CoreML
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import StableDiffusion

final class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var model: String = "/Users/mohalibou/Desktop/stuff/AnythingV3"
    @Published var scheduler: StableDiffusionScheduler = .dpmSolverMultistepScheduler
    @Published var configuration: MLComputeUnits = .cpuOnly
    
    var pipeline: StableDiffusionPipeline?
    
    func generateImages() async throws {
        print("Starting...")
        let configuration = MLModelConfiguration()
        configuration.computeUnits = self.configuration
        
        print("Configuration complete. Creating pipeline...")
        do {
            let modelURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: model)
            
            pipeline = try StableDiffusionPipeline(
                resourcesAt: modelURL,
                controlNet: [],
                configuration: configuration,
                disableSafety: true,
                reduceMemory: false
            )

        } catch {
            print("Error initializing pipeline: \(error)")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error when running the `generateImages()` function:

`Error initializing pipeline: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “merges.txt” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/mohalibou/Desktop/stuff/AnythingV3/merges.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000028b8e40 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}`

I am unsure what is causing this error. I have checked the permissions, and I should be able to read/write on these files.

I have seen suggestions of people saying to use the following commands:

```
url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

This has not worked for me, sadly.

Comment: To use `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource(` you have to create first a security scoped bookmark. In a sandboxed app the desktop of the current user is not accessible.